# Database Restoration

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

I am little bit confused in database backup process.

Suppose, I have one database named "A" and I created another database name  "B". Database "B" have same structure like database "A". In short Database "A" and "B" are same in table's structure but just database names are different only.

So Is it possible to restore database "A" in database "B"?

If it is possible then tell me command for it.

**Note: Both databases are on different Servers.**

Comment: I am using MySql. @Thilo

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup mydumper -h <host> -P 3306 -u <user> -p <pwd> -t 4 -m -B <dbname1> -o /root/test/mydumper_<dbname> &
```

dump the data without table structure;

```
nohup myloader -h <host> -P 3306 -u <user> -p <pwd> -e -B <dbname2> -d /root/test/mydumper_<dbname>/ &
```

restore the data into dbname2;

Just ignore the table structure, dump the data into SQL;